# Can I use a bike-sharing in Germany as a traveler?

Tags: germany, bicycles

I found that some people use a bike-sharing service, the one similar to mobike/ofo in China.

For example I found a bike below, which one person rode and left it behind, and then another person used it.

[image]

This service is likely [*Call a Bike*](https://www.callabike-interaktiv.de/de) but there seem to be [other providers around there](http://the-red-relocators.com/relocation-guides-germany/travelling/bike-sharing/).

But is it possible for a traveler to use one of them? I don't have an official residence in Germany (non-EU citizen), don't have a bank account in Germany, and don't understand German language, for your information. I have a phone number and passport, and temporary address on a room booked on AirBnB.

Comment: Below are good answers on registration. The complicated thing is the business area. For Call-a-Bike there rules differ a bit from city to city whether you can leave the bike anywhere in the area or only at bike stations etc. So you have to find and check those rules, else it can be expensive for returning at wrong place

Answer (score 8):

Germany has two big bike sharing providers, being present in many of Germany's bigger cities. However, service quality varies a lot, so make sure to pick one that has many bikes in the city you are traveling to. You won't need a German address for either of them.

### [DB Rent ("Call a Bike")](https://www.callabike-interaktiv.de/en/register)

Call a Bike is found in many cities. It is also the operator of 'Lidl Bikes' in Berlin, 'Konrad' in Kassel and 'Stadtrad' in Hamburg. You are able to use all of them with the Call a Bike account.

For registration you need to provide your address, telephone number and credit card. Note that there is a yearly base fee of €3 involved.

### [nextbike](https://nextbike.com/account/?lang=en)

Also nextbike can be found in most German cities. Mostly operating under the nextbike brand, they also provide the service for KVB Rad in Cologne, PotsdamRad and many many more. Nextbike operates worldwide: https://nextbike.com/#locations

You only need a credit card and a telephone number. No base fee as far as I know.

Answer (score 6):

For the Call a Bike service by Deutsche Bahn, it appears that you can. Their [terms of service](https://www.callabike-interaktiv.de/pdf/connect/AGB_DB%20Connect_Fahrradvermietung.pdf) only state that you need to be at least 18 years of age (also they reserve the right to check your credit score, but I don't think this is going to be enforced as the service is also [recommended to tourists](http://www.insidersberlin.com/144/call-a-bike-berlin/) in many places).
I just went through the first steps of their [registration](https://www.callabike-interaktiv.de/de/registrieren) and it appears to me all you will need is a credit card they can charge. Why not try?
Also for actually renting out bikes they have an app which is probably easier to use than make a call. There is an English-language [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_a_Bike) that helps a bit.

Comment: Of course entering "bogus info" could be interpreted as fraud.

Comment: @o.m. let me clarify, I entered that info on 1st step to see how the 2nd step looks like, of course I do suggest that one enters correct information when actually making the application. Otherwise, as you correctly state, this is fraud. Let me see if I can clarify this.